# how to raise an excpetion and return none value when the conditions are not satisfied

Tags: exception

I am new to python and have just to learn python. I have a written a code to find the common characters in two string and I am getting the desired output. I want to modify the code if the following cases arise and it should return `None` for the following conditions

```
1) For two string, if there is no match
2) any of string1 or string2 is nil/empty
3) any of string1 or string2 is hash/array/set/Fixnum [i.e anything other than string]
```

I am supposed to raise an exception for the above cases. I have gone through the forums and links but could not figure it out correctly. Could anyone please help me on how do raise exception for the above condition

This is the code

```
class CharactersInString:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2


    def find_chars_order_n(self):
        new_string = [ ]
        new_value1 = list(self.value1)
        new_value2 = list(self.value2)
        print( "new_value1: ", new_value1)
        print( "new_value2: ", new_value2)
        for i in new_value1:
            if i in new_value2 and i not in new_string:
                new_string.append(i)
        final_list = list(new_string)
        return ''.join(final_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = CharactersInString("ho", "killmse")
    print(obj.find_chars_order_n())
```

Comment: can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this.. I am unable to figure out the correct synatx for the try and except block